# C# TFS workspace.get() files updated

Tags: c#, tfs

So in this case I'm trying to get latest on all of my files using the `workspace.get()` function. However, this does not return the list of files that were updated, it just gets latest on them and then gives you a GetStatus object. Is there a way to know which files were updated? (just the file path is fine)

**Edit per request**

I'll try to clarify better...I'm literally trying to use the workspace.Get() function (on my workspace object that I already have) and instead of just getting a status i want to know the actual file names that were updated.

Comment: Show what you have done so far (source code?), and state what specifically you are having problems with

Comment: Edited even though it's basically saying the same thing again.

Comment: So.. You want to do a diff between your local workspace and the latest version on the server?

Comment: Yeah basically the list of all things that aren't the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I found to do it was to grab all of the items using the `GetItems()` method on the `VersionControlServer` object and manually loop through the items, adding ones that are new and deleting anything that now has a `DeletionId`

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do it that might be more useful is outlined here:

You can subscribe to the `VersionControlServer.Getting` event in your code, which will tell you when things are being gotten (i.e. when a file is different on the server to your local workspace, and so a get/delete is required).

On your VersionControlServer, subscribe to the Getting event:

```
vcs.Getting += Getting;
```

and then you can make the Getting method:

```
internal static void Getting(Object sender, GettingEventArgs e)
{
    //'e' has lots of properties and methods to help you figure out what has been done with the files.
}
```

`Getting` will be called each time an item is downloaded.

`e`'s properties include:

- `ChangeType` (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.changetype(v=vs.80).aspx)
- `DiskUpdateAttempted`
- `IsDelete`

See also:

- Description of GettingEventArgs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.gettingeventargs_members(v=vs.80).aspx
- the Getting event: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.versioncontrol.client.versioncontrolserver.getting(VS.80).aspx
- this helpful blog entry: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/buckh/archive/2005/01/22/358674.aspx